# Android tablet bootup very slow

Tags: boot

Earlier today, I was using my tablet. It ran out of battery so I charged it.

Then my tablet got stuck at the logo screen. I booted into recovery and cleared the `/cache` partition.

Finally, I realized that the tablet was not stuck, it was taking a very long time to boot!

I wait at the boot screen for about 3 minutes, then it changes to the loading image (which for me is a lot of moving tiles).

Why does it take so long all of a sudden?

Specs:

- Tablet: Kobo Arc original White 32GB version
- Processor: TI OMAP4470
- RAM: 1GB
- Graphics card: PowerVR

Comment: Did you install any system tweaks like Xposed? I am finding them slowing down Android booting. Even more different versions of Xposed cause significantly variable slowdown effect.

Comment: @iBug To avoid bricking it (like my previous 2 tablets), I haven't customized anything.

Comment: That's over-cautious. I often modify `/system` and `/data` after a backup. It's safe if you only touch the ext4 partitions after backing up. As long as you don't touch anything else there's nothing to worry about.